# workaround for using wildcards in Selenium IDE for assert text

Tags: xpath, selenium-ide

I want to use Selenium IDE to open [this webpage](https://concept.droppages.com/)  and check to see if some text is contained in a specific place

At the moment I can only match for the **entire** text `First-Play Zoft Touch Dodgeball, Red`

To do this I use

```
Command | Target | Value

`assert text` `xpath=//div[@id='vvp-items-grid']/div/div/div/a/span/span[2]` `First-Play Zoft Touch Dodgeball, Red`
```

Now, because Selenium IDE does't support wildcards at the moment I have to use a [method that makes my brain hurt](https://www.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/docs/en/introduction/faq/#how-can-i-use-regex-in-text-verifications)

My objective is to see if the word "dodgeball" is present. How the heck do I use `contains` and `dodgeball` in conjunction with that xpath locator?

What's really confusing to me is that there's a `.,` in the [example given](https://www.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/docs/en/introduction/faq/#how-can-i-use-regex-in-text-verifications) ? Why is that there? Is to "escape" ? because it's extremely confusing and unreadable to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.` character in XPath is a reference to the *context node*. Think of this as the "current" node which provides the context in which an XPath expression is evaluated. You could see it as analogous to the `this` keyword in some object-oriented languages.

The `[` and `]` characters are used in XPath to define a *predicate*, which is a filter, applied to a set of nodes selected by the portion of the XPath expression which is to the left of the predicate. The predicate filters that set of nodes to produce a subset containing just the nodes for which the boolean expression contained inside the predicate evaluates to `true`. The XPath processor takes each node in the nodeset, one by one, and evaluates the expression with that node as the context node. So a `.` in the predicate is a reference to the node which the filter is currently deciding on.

e.g. if `$x` is a nodeset, then `$x[true()]` is the same set, because the XPath function `true()` always returns `true`, regardless of the context node. The expression `$x[contains(., 'dodgeball')]` will return the subset of nodes in the set `$x` whose string value contains the string `dodgeball`.

You can use `assertElementPresent` with an XPath like this:

```
//div[@id='vvp-items-grid']/div/div/div/a/span/span[2][contains(., 'Dodgeball')]
```

Here, the first part of the XPath expression (`//div[@id='vvp-items-grid']/div/div/div/a/span/span[2]`) will return a set of `span` elements, and the predicate that follows it (`[contains(., 'Dodgeball')]`) will be evaluated once for each element in that set, with `.` referring to each element in question, and producing a new nodeset which contains only elements which do contain the `Dodgeball` text.

Note that the [`contains`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-contains) function is case sensitive; if you want to find `Dodgeball` you'll need to use the string `Dodgeball`, not `dodgeball`. If you want to perform a case-insensitive comparison, you need to use the [`translate`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-translate) function to convert the text you're looking at in your XML into either upper- or lower-case, and compare that result to an upper- or lower-case version of your keyword. e.g. Instead of

```
contains(., 'Dodgeball')
```

... you could use:

```
contains(
   translate(
      ., 
      'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 
      'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
   ), 
   'DODGEBALL'
)
```

Comment: Thank you - this works! I want to teach myself all this - my brain hurts just trying to understand it. I will re-read it multiple times until it sinks in!

Comment: Is there anything I can do to make it case insensitive? Because I will be changing the keyword, and it will sometimes have uppercase letters.  (Maybe there is no solution - it seems that xpath has to be very precise!)

Comment: As I will be changing the keyword a lot, can I make the keyword a variable in a previous step? Would that still work in xpath?

Comment: For case-insensitivity in XPath 1.0 you need to use the `translate` function <https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-translate> to convert  the text in the XML document to be in the same case as your search term: e.g. `contains(translate(., 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'), 'DODGEBALL')`

Comment: Sorry I don't know enough about Selenium to be able to suggest how to pass your keyword as a parameter to the XPath expression.